# How to add views from right-to-left to HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, right-to-left, horizontalscrollview

i have a horizontalscrollview with a LinearLayout inside, i add some views to linear layout , the views are buttons! but the thing is they add to linear layout from left to right , i want them to add from right to left , how can i achieve this?

this is my layout :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/filteringSearchBox"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filteringHeaderLL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

i played around with layoutDirection and gravity , none of them works
please give me full answer

this is the code :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mFilteringWB.length; i++) {
        Button mButton = new Button(mContext);
        mButton.setId(i);
        mButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6D6D6D"));
        mButton.setTextSize(13);
        mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shad_filtering);
        mButton.setTypeface(mFace);
        mButton.setText(mFilteringWB[i]);
        mLayout.addView(mButton);
    }
```

Comment: add your code that adds those buttons to the scrollview.

Comment: @hasan83 i added the code , edited my question , i want to have button 0 in the most right side linearlyout , means i want to start layout order from right to left

Comment: you will have to scroll again to the desired position after you add a new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [addView(View child, int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)) instead of [void    addView(View child)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View))

```
mylinearLayout.add(myButton, 0); // add new views to index 0 which is left
```

Comment: app crashes on this , says length is 6 and count=0 !

Comment: @MahdiGiveie at which line you got that error ? I think it's related to another thing

Comment: @hasan83 this line :    mLayout.addView(mButton,1);

Comment: @MahdiGiveie why 1? it must be 0, are you want to statically have some view in the first position"0" ?

Comment: mLayout.addView(mButton,0); not mLayout.addView(mButton,1); re-test please.

Comment: @hasan83 oh okay! 0 now works but now problem is : when i have more items the focus goes to left , means i need to scroll to left to see most first item which is on most right position of layout, how to set scrollview to be set always at right?